# callback for AKButton in Audiokit

Tags: swift, callback, audiokit

I am trying to understand how to attach callbacks to buttons on AudioKit, following the instructions on [Audiokit Docs](http://audiokit.io/docs/Classes/AKSampler.html#/c:@M@AudioKit@objc(cs)AKSampler(im)playWithNoteNumber:velocity:channel:error:) my code:

```
import UIKit
import AudioKit
import AudioKitUI

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let sounds = AKSampler()
    @IBOutlet weak var tam: AKButton!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        do {
            let hiTomFile = try AKAudioFile(readFileName: "hi_tom_D2.wav")
            try sounds.loadAudioFiles([hiTomFile])
            AudioKit.output = sounds
        } catch {
            print ("error reading file")
        }
        do {
            try AudioKit.start()
        } catch {
            AKLog("AudioKit did not start!")
        }
        // Bad access here!
        tam.callback = { button in self.sounds.play() }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

But I got a bad access. Any hints on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Looks fine at a glance, can you share the project?  Is the outlet properly hooked up?

Comment: Hello Aurelius! Yes I suspect there is something wrong with the hook. I just created a button using the interface, an UIButton actually, but I see AKButton derives from UIView, and I dont see how to cast, I am a newbie on swift/iOS, sorry. I'd placed the code on github: https://github.com/juan-barragan/mixer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get your button working.  You had in your storyboard a UIButton but I created a generic UIView, changed the class to "AKButton" from the module "AudioKitUI" and then connected it to your "tam" declaration and on click it runs the callback, no error.

Comment: Thanks Aurelius, I did that: creating UIView, I hooked it using IBOutlet and changed the type to AKButton! it compiles fine but still bad access.

Comment: This is just being an Xcode newbie, nothing much more but bang your head into the wall until you get it right. I literally opened up your project, made those changes (deleted a missing Conductor reference) and it ran and did not crash.